# ImportError: cannot import name 'MarianMTModel'

Tags: python, machine-learning, huggingface-transformers

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torchvision
from transformers import MarianTokenizer, MarianMTModel
from typing import List
```

I'm getting

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MarianMTModel'
```

I've already installed transformers. What can I do to solve this issue?
**Edit** : Does this import Marian model implemented in C++?

Comment: Can you manually check if  'MarianMTModel' is present in transformers package manually

Comment: What is the output of: `import transformers` and `transformers.__version__`?

Comment: @cronoik, it is 4.5.1

Comment: Check the directory of `transformers.__file__` if there is MarianMTModel.